# InputGroup not taking remaining space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap with a project and one component is having code as below. I want the **input and button to appear together and take up the whole space provided by the Col**. These both(input and button) are showing up together but the complete space is not occupied. Please Help!

```
<Row>
        <Col  xs={12} md={10} mdOffset={1} >

            <Form className="addGoalForm" inline onSubmit={
                handleSubmit
            } >
                <FormGroup className="addGoalForm">
                    <InputGroup>
                        <FormControl ref={textInput} type="text"/>

                    </InputGroup>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit"> Add Goal </Button>
                </FormGroup>



            </Form>

        </Col>
        </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the `inline` prop off from the Form

Comment: not working. that moved the button to the next line.

Comment: Also move the button to be within the InputGroup

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

The problem with your code is, you created an outer column, and added two elements inside it, they will just stack to the left - this is default behavior.

**Solution:**

Add column size for both input and button.

**How?**

1. Bootstrap col-xs-10 for input and col-xs-2 for button to occupy col-xs-12 of parent(consider your grid size for md, l sizes)
2. Create custom classes with width 80%/20% or as required.